# Sharing CPU limits for containers within a pod

Tags: kubernetes, resources, openshift, throttling, cgroups

In Openshift/Kubernetes, I want to test how my application (pod) that consists of 2 containers performs on machines with different number of cores. The machine I have at hand has 32 cores, but I'd like to limit those to 4, 8, 16...

One way is using resource limits on the **containers**, but that would force me to set the ratio on each container; instead, I want to set resource limits for whole pod and let the containers compete on CPU. My feeling is that this should be possible, as the containers could belong to the same cgroup and therefore share the limits from the scheduler POV.

Would the `LimitRange` on pod do what I am looking for? LimitRange is project/namespace -scoped, is there a way to achieve the same with finer granularity (just for certain pods)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container): resource constraints are only applicable on container level. You can however define different `requests` and `limits` to allow the container to burst beyond the amount defined in requests. But this comes with other implications see [Quality of Service](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/resource-qos.md).

The reason for this is that some resources such as memory cannot be competed about, as it works for CPU. Memory is either enough or too less. There is no such thing in Kubernetes as shared RAM. (If your are not explicitly call the relevant systemcalls)

May I ask, what the use case for Pod internal CPU competition is?

Comment: Both containers functionally cooperate on the task and I don't want to look for the optimum ratio between the containers; all I want is to assign N cores to the logical task.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation. IMHO this is a valid usecase. As decribed in the answer it is currently not possible. I think you will to invest some time on researching the optimum. I would limit one container to e.g. one cpu and then measure the CPU load of the other unrestricted container. This way you get your ratio which you can apply to the number of CPU's you want to use. This however assumes a stable ration which does not change over time. BTW i would be thankfull if you accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to accept it... at least you confirmed what seemed to be the case. Btw., do you know if LimitRange would do what I was looking for? Assuming that I can create a separate namespace for the pod...

Comment: Thank you. No, limitranges set only default ressource requests and limits if none are present...

Answer (score 0):

How about controlling resource usage inside your K8S cluster with resource quota. This should enable you to benchmark cpu/memory usage by your pod inside dedicated namespace with help of kube_resourcequota monitoring metrics, under different conditions set with LimitRange or directly with Container`s resources limits & requests.

What I mean exactly is to set **resource quota** similar to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-memory-cpu-namespace/#create-a-resourcequota) one:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: mem-cpu-demo
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "1"
    requests.memory: 1Gi
    limits.cpu: "2"
    limits.memory: 2Gi
    pods: "1"
```

run pod with **resource limits and requests**:

```
 ...
 containers:
    - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: hello-app
      ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 800Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 900m
          memory: 600Mi 
  ...
```

and just observe in monitoring console how the pod performs* for instance with Prometheus:

[image]

*
Green - represents overall memory usage by Pod, 
Red - fixed/hard resource limits set with ResourceQuota

I guess you opt for reducing the gap between lines to avoid undercommitted system, and at the same time avoid Pod failures like this one:

```
  status:
    message: 'Pod Node didn''t have enough resource: cpu, requested: 400, used: 893,
      capacity: 940'
    phase: Failed
    reason: OutOfcpu
```

Of course ideally would be if this memory usage trend were stack on cockpit chart with some other custom/performance monitoring metric of your interest.

Comment: IIUC the ResourceQuota only enforces that resource limits are set and that the sum of requested resource is not over threshold; it does not affect scheduling itself.